# Visual Studio 2017 Android NDK math.h

Tags: c++, android-ndk, linker, visual-studio-2017, math.h

I'm trying to port some OpenGL ES code from windows to Android using the Android NDK. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and C++. What I did so far, I created a cross platform gles project in VS and removed the ios data. I'm putting one code file after the other and try to fix any errors I can find.

The issue I have is that is seems that `math.h` functions can't be found.

Here's some information that might be relevant:

- Platform toolset is clang 3.8
- Target API Level is android-21
- Language standard is c++11
- I have added `m;` as an option to linker library dependencies

If i include `math.h` I get:

> use of undeclared identifier 'sqrt' (and all the other math.h functions I'm using)

If i include `cmath` I get:

> no member names 'acos' in the global namespace (and all the other cmath functions)

Path for files (as found by Visual Studio):

`c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b\platforms\android-21\arch-x86\usr\include\math.h`

`c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\cmath`

If I remove all math calls, it compiles.

Has anyone managed to use cmath in this context? If so, do you have any tips or point to what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you `#include <cmath>` The methods are in `std` namespace so you should use `std::acos` etc.

Comment: When I include <cmath> there's an error for every cmath function with `no member named 'function' in the global namespace`. In the header file there are some `using ::function` declarations.

Answer (score -1):

I have not found a fix to the questions, but creating a project from the native android template allows you to use `cmath` without error, but you do need to add `m;` in linker input.

Comment: hi, I am having the same issue, would you be able to provide some guidance?

Comment: If i remember correctly, the issue was that i was starting from an "OpenGLES Application" which is for both Android and iOS. I'm not entirely sure what the issue was, but if you create a "Native-Activity Application" (New Project > Visual C++ > Cross Platform > Android) it should work. Also remember that from that point forward to treat your code like you're writing for Linux (Android).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for all functions. While the sqrt function works, the clang and gcc compiler quits with error code 1 when I try to use the pow function.